# Ubuntu One (U1) closing down; any European alternative for OpenID?

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, openid

Ubuntu One is closing down and since I use it to log into SE I'm looking for an alternative. The objective is to add it as an additional login.

I've considered signing up for an SE account and then add it as my login alternative. Am I allowed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone comes up with a better alternative, I'll start using Swiss-based `clavid` at least for the time being.